# How to write an abstraction layer to hide DOM element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, abstraction

I want to hide all DOM element in my jquery scripts by an abstraction layer.

for example HTML elements are like this

```
 <input type="button"   id="connectButton" value="Connect"    />
 <input type="button"   id="hangupButton" value="Hangup" disabled="disabled"/>
```

and hangup click is  like this

```
 $('#hangupButton').click(function () {

                     helper.disable($('#hangupButton'));
                     helper.enable($('#connectButton'));

});
```

and I have defined a abstraction layer like following

```
//The NameSpace
var LPConnectWeb = LPConnectWeb || {};

//all classes 
LPConnectWeb.controlPanel =
{
    HangUp:  $("#hangupButton"),
    Connect: $('#connectButton'),
}
```

and access these element like following, but I am  unable to do

```
        LPConnectWeb.controlPanel.HangUp.click();
```

Comment: What is your issue? What click is supposed to do? Any bound handler? What type of element is `hangupButton`? Is `App.IsConnected` returning truly value? Etc... Provide at least relevant HTML markup in question itself

Comment: FYI, `onbeforeunload` doesn't wait for sync behaviour to complete, not in a cross broswer way. So you should debug it and try to isolate your issue. If your code `LPConnectWeb.controlPanel.HangUp.click();` works outside this handler, then issue comes from the behaviour of this specific event. Anyway, the use of `onbeforeunload` event doesn't really make sense to me here

Comment: I just want to access HTML via my abstraction class.

Comment: But again, what is the purpose of calling it from `onbeforeunload`? I don't get your logic. So question, how do you check it doesn't work? And please, don't edit question removing important part of code (onbeforeunload handler) without word in question itself regarding edit

Comment: jQuery is already an abstraction layer for DOMElements, beside that you problem is most likely that `HangUp:  $("#hangupButton")`  is done at a time where no element with the id  `hangupButton`  is in the DOM and because of that  it would be an empty result set (`LPConnectWeb.controlPanel.HangUp.length == 0`)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to wrap your query selection inside inline function, to get the target element once loaded in DOM tree

```
LPConnectWeb.controlPanel =
{
    HangUp:  function() { return $("#hangupButton"); },
    Connect: function() { return $('#connectButton'); }
}
```

Then, call it once DOM is ready

```
LPConnectWeb.controlPanel.HangUp().click();
```

Comment: It's not that the element is returned once the DOM tree is loaded. jQuery simply searches for the element on each call to `HangUp()`. While this would probably work, it seems OP was trying to get the element once and hold a reference to it.

Comment: I meant by wrapping it inside function, is to delay the search operation a little bit, and make all operations once DOM tree is loaded, because the initial solution holds a reference for non-existent elements.

Comment: Not if the js comes at the end of the html document.

Answer (score -1):

Update

http://jsbin.com/gerigajida/6/edit?html,js,output

Your example code definitely works. Click the arrow in the upper right to open the rendered output in a new tab. Open your browser dev tools console and run LPConnectWeb.controlPanel.HangUp.click()

Works for me.

Had to remove the "helper" code since "helper" doesn't exist in the example. Had to use alert instead of console.log since jsbin steals the console variable.

Also you are really asking 2 questions. The 2nd questions is "why doesn't this code work?". But to answer your primary question, here is some example code from a live site: http://pastie.org/9999962

The author sets up many variables using jQuery initially then only uses those variables throughout the rest of his code.

Comment: Semicolons in JavaScript are used to separate statements, but they can be omitted if the statement is followed by a line break (or there’s only one statement in a {block}).

Comment: In jsbin it wouldn't work unless I put that semi colon there. I guess that means his example code already works as is and there's something else wrong with the code he didn't include in his example.

Comment: It is indeed true that jsbin shows an error message that a semicolon is missing, but this error message does not prevent the code form running in jsbin, because this missing semicolon is not an error JavaScript.